# Median filter's out is wrong. What is the right median filter algorithm?

Tags: matlab, filter, median

I want to write a 1-D median filter for eliminating glitches from the signal. 
I wrote my median filter code on matlab and ı compare it with medfilt1 function out. My median filter is not working.

-- My median filter order is 8.

In my implementation, 
when data comes, I fill the array( size of the array is 8).
When incoming data count is 8, I take the middle value and write this
middle value to the median filter output array. And then I wait for the next 8 data. when ı take the 8 data, ı take the middle value and write this middle value to the median filter output array. and so on. (I implement sorting algoritm and ı test it. it is working good).

here is my screenshots,

my incoming data's color is red.
matlab's medfilt1's out is green.
my median filter's out is blue.

[Overall picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz2Nu.png)

[blown-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwpV5.png)

I think my algorithm is wrong, but I don't know what is the right algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is wrong, probably in two ways (hard to tell as you didn't show us your code).

1. You should be scrolling 1 element at a time, not 8 elements at a time.  That is, you should drop just the oldest element and add just the newest element, before taking the median.  (Note that your output has a frequency 8 times too high because you are replacing all 8 elements.)
2. You say that you *take the middle value*.  The middle value is not the median.  But perhaps you forgot to tell us that you do a sort first?